# Why does this modifier require an lvalue?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens

I copied this code from the Ethereum website and changed the outdated code that the compiler would not accept. However, previously I had no trouble with this modifier (show in the picture) as it now requires me to make the expression an lvalue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rctob.png

Answer (score 5):

You're doing an assignment, not a comparison. You need `==` for the comparison, not `=`.

```
require(msg.sender == owner);
```